# php regex to get id from url

Tags: php, regex

I have an url like this

```
http://localhost/MyProjects/client-contacts/?client=2
```

In php regex I want to get the id from the url. In the above url the id is 2. So can someone tell me how to get id from the url? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: `\d+$` will work for the above.

Comment: One example doesn't count as a spec...

Answer (score 2):

Don't use regular expressions for this.

You can use [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str) and [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) in combination:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/MyProjects/client-contacts/?client=2';
parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $arr);
echo $arr['client'];
```

Comment: +1 for parse_url instead of regex.

Answer (score 1):

Well, use this regex:

```
(\d)$
```

if it always is last, or use `?client=(\d)`. In both the cases, Group 1 will contain the id you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below regex to match the number which was present just after to `client=`,

```
client=\K\d+
```

OR

```
http:\/\/.*?=\K\d+
```

OR

`\d+$` will work for the above input.

Answer (score 0):

```
.*\/.*?(\d+)$
```

Try this.grab the capture.see demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dN8sA5/3

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$url = 'http://localhost/MyProjects/client-contacts/?client=2';
preg_match('/client=([a-z0-9]+)$/i', $url, $id);
echo $id[1];
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$url = 'http://localhost/MyProjects/client-contacts/?client=2';
preg_match('/client=([a-z0-9]+)$/i', $url, $mc);
echo $mc[1];      // here u get id as 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method could be:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/MyProjects/client-contacts/?client=2';
$url_parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($url_parts['query'],$output);
```

Outputs all parameters in the given URL:

array (size=1)
  'client' => string '2' (length=1)

so -> `$output['client']`

Answer (score 0):

Another method could be...
       $var = "http://localhost.com/MyProjects/client-contacts/?client=2";
       $id=explode("=", $var);
       echo $id[1];